# Copy SharePoint Online list Data to another one in the same Site

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-designer

I need to copy the list data (386 items) with lookup columns to another list with the same type of fields.

1. Data in the first list is migrated data from SharePoint 2010 using Metalogix tool.
2. The second list will be having the Nintex form but with the same fields.

I tried to copy the data through designer workflow and only one column is getting copied but not the rest (i have more than 60 columns).

I tried to copy through quick edit option, but getting an error 
"The information cannot be pasted because the Copy area and the Paste area are not the same size and shape "

I tried to copy the data column-wise through quick edit mode and somehow the rows are getting sorted and I am not getting the correct data to the corresponding cells.

Is there a way to copy the items ???

Comment: please show the code that you tried..

Comment: For Excel sheet there is no code just used Copy Paste options and for the designer workflow i used the create list item condition.